# Extension methods not showing even on implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my code:

```
    class myClass : IEnumerable
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> dctIdName = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        public myClass()
        {
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 100; idx++)
            {
                dctIdName.Add(idx, string.Format("Item{0}", idx));
            }

        }

        // IEnumerable Member
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (object o in dctIdName)
            {
                yield return o;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where i create an object of this class and use it in this manner i do not get the LINQ extension methods like `Where`, `Count`, etc.

```
myClass obj = new myClass();
var d = obj.Where( x => x.Key == 10); //<-- Error here
```

The namespaces i have included are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Most extension methods are for the generic `IEnumerable<T>`, not the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *does* work. [`AsParallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413237(v=vs.100).aspx) is an extension method on `IEnumerable`. Most extension methods though work on `IEnumerable<T>`. Your class should start with this:

```
class myClass : IEnumerable<SomeType>
```

Or:

```
class myClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

(Where `T` is the type of the generic type argument)

---

```
class myClass : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dctIdName = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public myClass()
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < 100; idx++)
        {
            dctIdName.Add(idx, string.Format("Item{0}", idx));
        }

    }

    // IEnumerable Member
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> o in dctIdName)
        {
            yield return o;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can call [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) for example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the generic version of IEnumerable. I guess in your case it would be:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
```

or

```
IEnumerable<object>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only the following extension methods are defined by the .NET Framework for [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

> AsParallel() - Enables parallelization of a query.(Defined by ParallelEnumerable.)
>
> AsQueryable() -  Converts an IEnumerable to an IQueryable.(Defined by Queryable.)
>
> Cast() - Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.(Defined by Enumerable.)
>
> OfType() - Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.(Defined by Enumerable.)

[`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't 'contain' the extension method, hence it are *extension* methods. Interfaces can't have method definitions.

Comment: Would the word 'defines' be more appropriate?

Comment: Well, some classes define extension methods for that interface, so that would be a better wording indeed, but it is the other way around.